# pop, a predefined function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

why I get errors?

first :
code :

```
    e = [1, 3, [-5, 0]]
e.pop (e[1])
print (e)
```

second:
code:

```
    e = [1, 3, [-5, 0]]
e.pop (e[2])
print (e)
```

Comment: What error did you get? what did you get when you researched that error?

Comment: you pass the index not the value to `pop()`. In your case you need to do ```e.pop(1)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
e.pop(1)
```

or

```
del e[1]
```

fixed:

```
e = [1, 3, [-5, 0]]
e.pop(1)
print (e)

e = [1, 3, [-5, 0]]
e.pop(2)
print (e)
```

output:

```
[1, [-5, 0]]
[1, 3]
```

replacing `e.pop(<index>)` with `del e[<index>]` yields the same output.